# NSFileManager - Список файлов в папке без скрытых и пакетов

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

И так, мне надо собрать в один массив все файлы из определенной папки с подпапками, НО без скрытых файлов и без пакетных файлов. 
Я использую:

```
NSEnumerator *tempArray1 = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtURL:url
                                           includingPropertiesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSURLNameKey, NSURLIsDirectoryKey, NSURLContentModificationDateKey, nil]
                                                              options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsPackageDescendants
                                                              errorHandler:nil];
NSLog(@"tempArray1: %@", [tempArray1 allObjects]);
```

Так вот, в options я могу указать "без скрытых" ИЛИ "без пакетных" (как в примере). Но я не могу указать обе настройки. получается, что либо - либо, а вместе нельзя.

Есть какой-нибуть способ собрать из папки файлы с подпапками?

PS: что бы окончательно понять вопрос, попробуйте сделать листинг в папке Movies без настройки "без пакетов". Там столько шлака.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо использовать битовую операцию сложения масок: NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsPackageDescendants | NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles

Comment: Вот спасибо, все получилось.